# Find files and delete x from total of the list

Tags: bash, find, rm

I want to delete all log files in some directory, but not the latest 3.

I've done:

```
DATA_PATH=$(gadmin config get System.DataRoot)
ZK_PATH=${DATA_PATH}/zk/version-2

log_count=$(ls -ltrh ${ZK_PATH} | grep log | wc -l)
limit_files=`expr $log_count - 3`

echo There is ${log_count} files found in ${ZK_PATH}, ${limit_files} will be deleted, here the list:
ls -ltrh ${ZK_PATH} | grep log | head -${limit_files}

while true; do
    read -p "Are you sure to delete these files? " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy1]* ) echo execute to delete the files; break;;
        [Nn0]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer y or n.";;
    esac
done
```

How can I delete 9 of 12 files listed?

I thought about printing the list to the files first and then delete it one by one using looping, but I am sure there is code to do it only with one line.

I try to use `find ... -delete`, `-exec`, and `xargs rm`, but I cannot use it properly.

How can I do it?

Comment: Re: `log_count=…`: [Why not to parse `ls` output (and what to do instead)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead); Grepping for `log` is also a bit strange; you could just have done something like `${ZK_PATH}/*log*` and gotten a list of the files, which is properly countable.

Comment: i try to use find and delete all the log files found, but i want to delete the files but no with the latest 3. like i found 12 log files, so i want to delete 9 files of it

Comment: yes, you wrote that. See my comment above.

Comment: is the find command already sort the files found by time modified?

Comment: You haven't written a `find` command, so we can't tell you whether you told it to do that. But also, find is not a useful tool here. As Stéphane's answer shows, this can be done through automated filename generation alone (see my first comment!). On its own, `find` can't, but you can decorate with time, zero-terminate, sort, de-decorate the things. Again, complicated and not necessary, as Stéphane's answer shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets you a list of all but the youngest `limit_files` files, which you can then remove.

```
FileList=`ls -1rt ${ZK_PATH}/*log* | head -${limit_files}`
rm $FileList
```

It won't work with files that contain spaces or other special characters, but the log files in my log directories only ever have alphanumeric characters, dash and period, so works perfectly.

Comment: Whether it fails of files with spaces depends on what you have in `$IFS`. `$IFS` also needs to contain the newline character as you rely on split+glob to split `$FileList`. None of the files must be directories, nor  *start* with a dash.

Answer (score 6):

Use zsh instead of bash where this kind of thing can be done much more easily and reliably:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
data_path=$(gadmin config get System.DataRoot) || exit
zk_path=$data_path/zk/version-2
keep=3

files=( $zk_path/*log*(N.om) )

if (( $#files > keep )); then
  printf >&2 '%s\n' "$#files files found in $zk_path, $(( $#files - keep )) will be deleted, here is the list from newest to oldest:"
  shift keep files
  printf >&2 ' - "%s"\n' $files:t

  read -q '?OK to delete? ' && rm -f -- $files
fi
```

Of special interest is the `$zk_path/*log*(N.om)` *glob*; it expands to all file names matching the pattern `*log*` in `$zk_path`, and the parentheses `(…)` specify that if no files are found, that's no error (`N`ullglob), that we're only looking for plain files and not directories, symbolic links, devices… (`.`), and that we want to have the files sorted in ascending `o`rder of age (based on `m`odification time, like `ls -t` does).

Comment: That's a very elegant approach there with the N-shift. Like it a lot!

Comment: Thanks, and  for the edit @Marcus

Comment: I felt a bit bad making that edit, it's your answer after all :)

Comment: Thank for the answer, i've tryed ```find . -name "log.*" | head -5 | xargs rm -r``` as a test and its looks work as far, but i still doubt. I just now about zsh, i'll learn about it, thanks for the answer and the knowladge

Comment: @YudhaRestu that is not sorted by date at all! Instead, it's just ordered in the order that `find` is presented with the files by the file system – which isn't guaranteed to follow any specific ordering. So, your `find` solution (in which the `find` is frankly a bit superfluous – `echo log.*` would have done the same) is complicated but wrong. Also very fragile! I sketched how you could do this correctly with find [in my previous comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/740331/find-files-and-delete-x-from-total-of-the-list#comment1406016_740331). Your solution really **isn't**.

Comment: @MarcusMüller. Don't. I've answered hundreds of questions with zsh glob qualifiers. Describing them every time is quite tedious. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @YudhaRestu see also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) for the good and bad ways to process `find`'s results.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, strictly speaking, some `find` implementations do or can do some ordering of the files based on inode number as an optimisation so the inode table can be read sequentially when find needs to get information from there like the file's type. In any case, the order will still appear random.

Answer (score 6):

In a similar situation I used the following approach (probably, this is not the most robust solution, but it still may be useful in common situation...)

```
LOGDIR=my/logs    ## 

ls -dpt -- "$LOGDIR"/log* | # get log files sorted by date
  grep -v '/$'            | # but remove directories/ from the list
  tail -n +4              | # remove also the newest 3
  vidir -
```

In `vidir`, if you agree, delete all the lines (example: use `dG` vim command), leave, and they get deleted.

`vidir` from `moreutils` is a projection-editor for directories (the best tool to see, rename, delete, directory contents)

Comment: Thank you for the edit @StéphnaneChazelas.